# How to minimize this sum?

Tags: optimization

Given $n$ positive number that $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=k$. I want to minimize $\sum \sqrt{x_i^2+1}$. I guess that this sum is minmum when $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$, but I cant prove it. can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Of course! my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(u) = \sqrt{u^2 +1} $ is convex. Using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form),

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum \sqrt{x_i^2 + 1} \ge \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum x_i\right)^2 +1} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 + 1}$$

with equality at $x_i = \frac{k}{n} ~\forall i$.